# SharePoint 2013 & 2010 Strange Issues

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-server

In the past 4 weeks we had 2 strange issues in our SP 2010 and SP 2013 Farm

Issue 1 :Firstly in our 2010 Farm we have 3 Servers ( 2 WFE and 1 App) and one day lot of our users complained  the error they are receiving "Server is too Busy Please try again later" when accessing the SharePoint sites ,after going through this we found that one of the Webfront end is giving this error and the other is fine so we did an IISRESET and after that the server is working fine for the past 2 weeks

Issue 2 :Then in our 2013 Farm we have 7 Servers ( 4 WFE and 3 App) and the next day users complained  they are receiving the same "Server is too Busy Please try again later" when accessing the SharePoint sites ,after going through this we found that again that one of the Web front end is giving this error and the others are fine so we did again an IISRESET and after that the server is working fine for the past  week

No we are going through the logs to find what happened but unfortunately we are not able to find much ,first we thought that as 2010 have old servers and may be they are just aging out but when the same happened in 2013 which is very new and have huge resources and so we ruled out that theory

Can you please suggest what caused this and what can we do in future to prevent this from happening again

ULS Logs

The below log entry repeated continuously in 2010 and only stopped after doing an IISRESET

> IOException in RefreshCache. Try # 0. Retrying. Exception message :The
>   process cannot access the file
>   'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\a7861004-c261-4fe2-9a3a-0b1294729c92\cache.ini'
>   because it is being used by another process

Comment: As it stands, there is not enough information to give any sort of reliable or accurate answer. If you have information from ULS logs that you think might be the culprit, please add them. Without any errors, this is too broad.

Comment: did you check the Event Log on the servers(WFE) during that time frame. I am sure you will get some HTTP thorttling related.Could you please confirm it?